# Argument controller is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am receiving the following error:

```
Argument 'mainController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Which is strange because the code worked before I started adding pages and content to the app.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="top" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <title>Website</title>

 <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="mainController">

<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/dashboard.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the settings page
        .when('/settings', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/settings.html',
            controller  : 'settingsController'
        });
});
```

I started my code from a template.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. 
For more details see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: No magic.. You need to define controller.

Comment: Is that not done by: <body ng-controller="mainController"> ?

Comment: He means in your javascript. It ain't there.

Comment: where is the controller in the javascript? i.e. `myApp.Controller('mainController', function() { ... }`

Comment: also, you can't use the same controller on the body that is going to be assigned to the `ng-view` by the route provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing ***referencing*** a controller instance in your html (which binds it) to actually ***creating*** your controller within your application.

Declare it off of your root app module.

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}]};
```

In addition, since you're declaring a template and a controller pair, you cannot bind your controller on the body element.  You should instead bind it within it's respective template.

```
<div class="menu" ng-controller="mainController">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you absolutely want it to be bound to the body element, remove it from your routing declaration.